# If $F$ is closed and $x \not\in F$, show that there are disjoint open sets $U,V$ such that $x \in U$ and $F \subset V$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, continuity

If $F$ is closed and $x \not\in F$,

(a) show that there are disjoint open sets $U,V$ such that $x \in U$ and $F \subset V$.

(b) Can $U$ and $V$ be chosen such that their closures $\bar{U} , \bar{V}$are disjoint as well ?

Attempt:
Assume $d(x,F) = t$

Consider the function $d(y,F)$ which is continuous, so the set $A = \{y | d(x,F) > t/2\}$ is open and contains $x$, similarly the set $B = \{y | d(x,F) < t/2\}$ is also open and contains F, both A and B are disjoint hence the required sets.

Can I consider the closure of the A and B for the second part (b) of the question?

Comment: In the real numbers if $x=0 $ and $F=\{1\}$ we have $t=1$ but $1/2\in \bar A \cap \bar B.$ Replace $t/2$ by $t/3$ in your proof to get disjoint $\bar A, \bar B.$

Answer (score 2):

One missing piece in this proof: You need to know that $t>0$ in order to prove that $A,B$ are open. So, for that purpose, you need to prove that $t>0$.

Regarding part (b), the closure of $A$ and $B$ might, by bad luck, contain the same point $z$, such that $d(z,F)=t/2$. However, you should be able to rewrite your proof to avoid that bad situation and obtain disjoint closures.

Comment: x $\not\in$ F and F is closed hence ..there is a \epsilon nighbourhood of x which is not in F ..t > 0, could you be more specific regarding the second part (b) ..... Thanks

Comment: To be more specific, here is a counterexample (with corrections to formulas for $A$ and $B$): $F = \{0\}$, $x=1$, $t=1$, $A = \{y | d(y,F) > 1/2\} =  (-\infty,-1/2) \cup (+1/2,\infty)$, $B=\{y | d(y,F) < 1/2\} = (-1/2,+1/2)$,  $\text{closure}(A) \cap \text{closure}(B) = \{-1/2,1/2\} \ne \emptyset$. Both $\text{closure}(A)$ and $\text{closure}(B)$ contain a point $z$ such that $d(z,F)=1/2$, namely $z=1/2$.

Answer (score -1):

Let r =d(x,F)/100

Now we define U=B(x,r) and V=UB(a,r)
a€F

Clearly, x€U and F is contained in V.

Then we claim that U and V are disjoint.
If not, then let there exists z€UnV.
=> d(x,z)<r and d(z,y) < r
⇒ d(x,y) < 2r= d(x,F)/50,which is a contradiction .
Hence our claim "U and V are disjoint " is true. Q.E.D

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Use MathJax formatting for mathematical expressions.